# twist message: angular velocity unit

Tags: ros, nav-msgs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Quick question, the nav_msgs: twist has angular component in x,y,z.
I view this as the velocity of rotation with respect to x-axis, y-axis, and z-axis. But what is the unit of such velocity. Degree/second or radiant/second?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/212296/twist-message:-angular-velocity-unit/) by [kuku123](https://answers.ros.org/users/22953/kuku123/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2015-06-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS uses SI units, specifically MKS.

That means for angular rate the default is radians/second.

All default units are defined in [REP 103](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0103.html)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2015-06-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2